# How to lookup property parameter in web app for log4j2?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

I want to configure `log4j2` to lookup the logging path dynamically from web startup (tomcat).

From the docs (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) there is a  `web:` lookup with different parameter possibilities.

At first I'm trying the provided example:

```
<Appenders>
   <File name="ApplicationLog" fileName="${web:rootDir}/app.log"/>
</Appenders>
```

Result: `ERROR Unable to create file ${web:rootDir}/app.log java.io.IOException`

I also tried the other buildin properties like `servletContextName` and `contextPath` with the same error message.

So I'm probably still missing something important. But what?

Comment: try creating the file in that location

Comment: Of course that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Add log4j-web JAR

Your usual `log4j-core` JAR file on its own is not enough.

There is an additional component called [`log4j-web`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-web).

For automatic replacement of the `${web:...}` placeholders in your logging configuration, you need the additional `log4j-web` JAR file. If you don't have this log4j-web JAR file, then Log4j2 itself will still work, but it will not replace these placeholders with anything. So for example `${web:rootDir}` will just end up as the literal text `${web:rootDir}`.

Perhaps you are missing that dependency in your project?

[Log4j-web on Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.logging.log4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22log4j-web%22)

Comment: Somehow even when including the module the $web plugin did not get activated. So I made a copy of `WebLookup` and activated it from `log4j2.xml` using `<configuration packages="path.to.plugin.package">`

Answer (score 0):

Is ${web:rootDir} a value? The placeholder is not replaced by its real value.

In the page you can red:

> Information on how to use Lookups in configuration files can be found in the Property Substitution: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

Comment: The value is stated by the page I linked above: `rootDir  Returns the result of calling getRealPath with a value of "/".`

Comment: Right, but I intend that it is possible ${web:rootDir} hasn't a value... are you sure there is a ServletContext available (e.g. did you define a log4jContextName param name in you web.xml context, if you're using a 3.0 servlet container)? I think you have a misconfiguration problem: try to fllow this: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Comment: I have an annotation based spring configuration, no xml config. And yes I'm sure there is a ServletContext avalable.

Comment: What servlet specifications your container implements? Also with spring your application need an web.xml file... By the way I'm sure reading http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html (in 2.5 or 3.0) you will find the suggestion you need for your case.

Comment: PS: See also this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003114/log4j2-weblookup-not-getting-resolved