# Why does the log4j2's ${web:rootDir} web lookup cause issues at the deployment in weblogic 12c?

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j2, weblogic12c

The log4j2's web lookup - `${web:rootDir}` seems to cause problems on weblogic 12c deployment.

I suspect that the log4j2 web-lookup plugin is not initialized when weblogic requests the logger at the start of deployment and is unable to create the file.

What I've done -

1. Added slf4j in weblogic preferred packages of weblogic.xml.
2. log4j-web dependency is present in classpath.

3.web.xml contains following:-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

*Note - Log4jServletContextListener is placed before all listeners.

-Have attached stacktrace for your reference.

```
2019-05-31 19:18:01,742 [STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR Unable to create file ${web:rootDir}/logs/Server.log
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:142)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:627)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:608)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:116)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger(LogManager.java:70)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:149)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:390)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:24)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
        at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.getDefaultValidationBean(ValidationManager.java:185)
        at weblogic.validation.injection.ValidationManager.bindValidation(ValidationManager.java:61)
        at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:497)
        at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindValidation(EnvironmentBuilder.java:489)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:194)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:2866)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1648)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:805)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:317)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:313)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:121)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:195)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:190)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:61)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Please assist.

Apache issue link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2/issues/LOG4J2-2624?filter=allopenissues

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm using servlet 2.5 environment and not servlet 3.0. Still, I'll check by adding <log4jContextName>

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it still produces same issue with the solution specified in your link.

Comment: are you using log4jContextName and servlet 3.0 now ?

Comment: it does not work with log4jContextName and servlet 2.5. I found an alternative to it with the log4jConfigParentLocation. But, it solves the error in weblogic gives errors in jboss.